# VBA: Find if values are the first instance present in a table

Tags: excel, vba

For another formula I need to know if specific values are the first occurrence in a table. For example,

```
Letter   Number   First Occurrence
  A        1           True
  A        2           True
  B        1           True
  C        4           True
  A        2           False
  C        2           True
  B        1           False
```

In other words, is there a way to know if something has already occurred in the table?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` and [mixed references](https://exceljet.net/glossary/mixed-reference):

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)=1
```

[image]